# Android Studio, keeps loading the same fragment

Tags: php, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm doing a simple Login Application, where the user simply logs in and when so, all the details are displayed. This is done through a php file, and a SQL datahost database.

When I input the incorrect credentials the app, it works fine by prompting the user with a error to retry, but when I give it the correct username and password, it reloads the page and does not take me to the MainActivity. I tried several methods and changing code with out any luck.

**This is the code to send the php located in thhe reponse.listener**

```
                        if (success) {
                            String name = "test";//jsonResponse.getString("name");
                            String surname = "test";//jsonResponse.getString("surname");
                            String username = "test";//jsonResponse.getString("username");
                            String email = "test";//jsonResponse.getString("email");
                            int phone = 123;//jsonResponse.getInt("phone");
                            int age = 23;//jsonResponse.getInt("age");
```

Here I'm calling the other activity from this fragment, and assigning the details in the right place.

```
                            Intent intent = new 
Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
                                intent.setClass(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                intent.putExtra("surname", surname);
                                intent.putExtra("username", username);
                                intent.putExtra("age", age);
                                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); //create an error message
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null) //click retry to retry registration
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        }  catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
```

**This is my php code, located on my hosting sql database**

```
    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("mysql4.000webhost.com", "a3826656_user", "", "a3826656_data");
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $surname, $username, $password, $email, $phone, $age);
        $response = array();
        $response["success"] = false;  
        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
            $response["success"] = true;  
            $response["name"] = $name;
            $response["surname"] = $surname;
            $response["age"] = $age;
            $response["username"] = $username;
            $response["password"] = $password;
            $response["email"] = $email;
            $response["phone"] = $phone;
       }
       echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**This is the LoginRequest**

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://lukecassar.net23.net/Login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener,null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

**Manifest Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mt.edu.mcast.navigationfragmentsexample">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the jsoan response?

Comment: Yes. and update your post where you parse success value.

Comment: W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for BlankFragment2{ecea29e #0 id=0x7f0c006c android:switcher:2131492972:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2

Comment: the part i parse success, is at the top

Comment: Did you give MainActivity permission in manifest?

Comment: Can you post your manifest file?

Comment: ok, its edited. Its at the bottom

Comment: You have only one Activity in manifest but what is the name of your login activity?

Comment: its a fragment, its called blankfragment1

Comment: That means your MainActivity hold the blank fragment. Luke Cassar your code is ok. When you logged in successfully your code open the same Activity. so that you could not understand. You Should make an another Activity which will be opening when login success.

Comment: yes thats what im trying to do, i have another activity which is the MainActivity, but its opening.

Comment: Which Activity hold your fragment?

Comment: i think the Main Activity :/

Comment: public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new BlankFragment1();
                case 1:
                    return new BlankFragment2();
            }
            return null;
        }

Comment: thats in the mainactivity

Comment: so if the fragment and the mainactivity are the same activity, can i switch from one view to the other?

Comment: In this case you shoud go another activity or another fragment. dont load same activity. because fragment is a part of Activity. Please follow the Activity and Fragment lifecycle from Android documentation.

Comment: Your code should be something like this e.g. Intent intent = new  Intent(getActivity(),HomeActitvity.class);

Comment: yes it worked, the fragment is part of the same activity thats why it was refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `startActivity(intent)` instead of `getActivity().startActivity(intent)` and delete this line `intent.setClass(getActivity(), MainActivity.class)` because you're already defining that on the intent constructor `Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class)`

Comment: same, W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for BlankFragment2{f3fef40 #0 id=0x7f0c006c android:switcher:2131492972:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2

Comment: Well put a breakpoint on the if statement and see what's going on.

Comment: Im still fresh to android studio. The if statment is working correctly, cause when i input incorrect username or password, success is false, prompting an error message. When i input correct credentials, the same activity pops again, while i want to pop the mainactivity. please not that the login form , is a fragment

Comment: What's the name of the class that is hosting your fragment? More info would be great too.

Comment: so if im correct, i have an the login page, which is a fragment, and the main activity. now the class of the loginpage is called BlankFragment1 while the main page is called MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the fragment was part of the activity i was calling, so since i was calling the same activity, it was simply refreshing.

I simply created an other activity and called the new intent.

Thanks to @Masum i came to this conclusion. Thanks